# Moving rectangles in opposite directions in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Forgive the noobness of question, completely new to JS.

I've successfully got a rectangle going back and forth in a canvas, and i want to add a second going opposite ways (or even up and down)

The only problem is that the second rectangle is static and I cant get it to move.

Can i place a new ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h) in the same function of my first square?

As atm it looks like this:

```
function drawSquare(ctx) {

    clearCanvas(ctx); 
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(xpos, 140, 20, 20);
    if(direction==="goright"){
        if(xpos<canvasWidth - 20){xpos = xpos + 5;}else{direction = "left";}
    } if(direction==="left"){
        if(xpos>0){xpos = xpos - 5;}else{direction = "goright";}   
    }
    // This is the second square i am having trouble with??
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(780, 200, 20, 20)

    if(direction==="goright"){
        if(xpos<canvasWidth - 20){xpos = xpos + 5;}else{direction = "left";}
    } if(direction==="left"){
        if(xpos>0){xpos = xpos - 5;}else{direction = "goright";}   
    }
```

I have my variables and other coding if needed to.
But do i need to set up a second direction var for the 2nd square?
Or do i need to set up a whole different function and new setInterval for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw your second rectangle **after** you've updated your `xpos` variable, aswell as use your `xpos` variable.

```
function drawSquare(ctx) {
    clearCanvas(ctx); 
    if(direction==="goright"){
        if(xpos<canvasWidth - 20){xpos = xpos + 5;}else{direction = "left";}
    } if(direction==="left"){
        if(xpos>0){xpos = xpos - 5;}else{direction = "goright";}   
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(xpos, 140, 20, 20);

    if(direction==="goright"){
        if(xpos<canvasWidth - 20){xpos = xpos + 5;}else{direction = "left";}
    } if(direction==="left"){
        if(xpos>0){xpos = xpos - 5;}else{direction = "goright";}   
    }
    // This is the second square i am having trouble with??
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(xpos, 200, 20, 20)
}
```

Here's a working snippet

```js
var
    ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d'),
    xpos = 0, t,
    canvasWidth = 256,
    direction = "goright"
; 

function drawSquare(ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,256,256); 
        if(direction==="goright"){
            if(xpos<canvasWidth - 20){xpos = xpos + 5;}else{direction = "left";}
        } if(direction==="left"){
            if(xpos>0){xpos = xpos - 5;}else{direction = "goright";}   
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(xpos, 140, 20, 20);
        
        if(direction==="goright"){
            if(xpos<canvasWidth - 20){xpos = xpos + 5;}else{direction = "left";}
        } if(direction==="left"){
            if(xpos>0){xpos = xpos - 5;}else{direction = "goright";}   
        }
        // This is the second square i am having trouble with??
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        t = window.performance.now();
        ctx.strokeRect(xpos + Math.cos(t * 0.001) * 32, Math.sin(t * 0.001) * 118 + 128, 20, 20)
    }

window.requestAnimationFrame(function draw() {
drawSquare(ctx);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="256" id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey LJ thanks,
I copied this into my text editor and i'm getting the error of cannot read property of 'getContext' of null
I obviously changed my html file to suit the write ID etc.

Is window.requestAnimationFrame the same as set.Interval(function.. or similar thing yes? Havn't used it yet.

Comment: Its *similar* yes, it executes whenever the browser is ready, but no more than 60 times per second. `setInterval` executes "always" even though the browser may not be ready or hasnt finished the last call. This can lead to performance issues for heavy applications. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). The visible code above is supposed the be "the answer" where the collapsed one is more for the eye candy ;)

Comment: Sweet, i will look to use that, is there anything else i should change?

Comment: Well some proper indention wouldnt hurt I guess. 
Also you may want to use objects to represent your boxes and use a loop to iterate over a list of them.

Comment: Will do, need rep a bit higher but np. ty